# How to call functions using ctypes with no input parameters?

Tags: python, ctypes

I am trying to call the C++ function add_two_U from Python using ctypes.  The function add_two_U is defined in the C++ header file as:

```
extern ExternalInputs_add_two add_two_U;
```

The structure ExternalInputs_add_two is defined in the header file as:

```
typedef struct {
  int32_T Input;                       /* '<Root>/Input' */
  int32_T Input1;                      /* '<Root>/Input1' */
} ExternalInputs_add_two;
```

The function add_two_initialize that I call in my Python code below is defined in the header file as:

```
extern void add_two_initialize(boolean_T firstTime);
```

My Python code:

```
import sys
from ctypes import *

class ModelInput(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("Input", c_int),
                ("Input1", c_int)]

#define the functions    
initiateModel = cdll.add_two_win32.add_two_initialize
U_Model = cdll.add_two_win32.add_two_U


# define the pointers to the functions
initiateModel.restype = c_void_p
U_Model.restype = c_void_p

#initialize the model with value of 1
print "\n\nInitialize"
errMsg = initiateModel(1)
print "initateModel reports:", errMsg

#Initialize the structure and get the pointer.
test_input = ModelInput(1,2)
input_ptr =  pointer(test_input)
```

I am trying to call function add_two_U in the python code thru the variable U_Model.  Notice in the header file that this function doesn't have any input parameters and uses the structure in the header file to get the input data.

I have the following 2 questions:

1. How do I set the structure ExternalInputs_add_two structure in my Python code to pass the data to the `add_two_U` function?
2. How do I call the dll function with no parameters `add_two_U` that I reference thru `U_Model` in the Python code?  If I use the Python statement to call the function:

   ```
   result = U_Model()
   ```

   I get the following error:

   ```
   WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0xFFFFFFFF
   ```

I've searched on-line for an answer and couldn't find an example of initializing a structure in a header file and calling a function with no parameters.

Notice in my Python code that I am able to call function add_two_initialize thru initiateModel with no errors since this function has input parameters.

Answer (score 1):

`add_two_U` is not a function, it's an exported value. You need to use `in_dll`.

See [Accessing values exported from dlls](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#accessing-values-exported-from-dlls).

Comment: @Scott I see from your other question that this appears to be your answer. Please could you mark it as such, by clicking on the tick next to this answer to make it go green. Please have a read of the FAQ for all the details.

Answer (score 0):

David,

Thank you for answering my first question.  I changed my Python code to this:

```
#Comment out this line.  add_two_U is not a function
#U_Model = cdll.add_two_win32.add_two_U

#Get the output pointer from add_two_U
output = POINTER(ModelInput)
results = output.in_dll(cdll.add_two_win32,"add_two_U")

print "got results", results.contents()
```

This code works.  I still can't figure out the answer to my first question: How to set initialize the structure ExternalInputs_add_two in the header file from Python code.

I've searched the ctypes documentation and can't find a function or examples on how to do this.  I realize it's probably in the documentation.

Comment: This space is reserved for answers to your question only. You should edit your original question to add additional information.